# custom floating action button shows white circle shade on clicking the button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I have created a custom floating action button and some how it shows a big cirucular trasparent border shaded on clicking that button. i wish to remove that cirlce and instead want to make that button glow on clicking , so that it gives user a feel that button was clicked. i would highly appreciate for any help.
[image: round circle formed on clicking fab button]

below is my xml design for floating action button.

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/alarm01"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="?android:attr/panelBackground"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight" 

    app:maxImageSize="110dp" />
```

Comment: Something with ripple effect / onclick effect. Not sure atm.